# How to fix error with JEST in react-create-app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I have a big problem with starting my project, which was cloned from git.
I try to write "npm i", for installing all packejest, after that write npm start, but I see an error.

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "jest": "24.7.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/nazarromanchuk/node_modules/jest (version: 24.9.0) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
...
```

I know to delete node_modules, package-lock.json and white one more time "npm i" - the same error

My package.json look:

```
{
  "name": "interview-question",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^1.28.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.16",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-compound-timer": "^1.1.5",
    "react-countdown-now": "^2.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.6.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also try to write in "dependencies" jest version 24.07.1, also remove node_modules, package-lock.json but it didn't change anything - the same error(
Also, I was added .env file with SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true but it also didn't help to fix my error

Can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you carefully look to this line :

```
 /Users/nazarromanchuk/node_modules/jest
```

it's directory in you Home directory . maybe you mistake and run `npm init` in you home directory ? could you please check `/Users/nazarromanchuk/` and remove package.json and `node_modules` folder ? and then change your directory (cd ) in your `interview-questions` modules and then run `npm i` or try with `yarn`

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade your jest in your system to the version of project. You can find it here:

```
/Applications/node_modules/package.json
```

In node modules directory: `npm install jest@24.7.1` (version of project)